# Thick head on Double IPA

Tags: beer

My double IPA when poured into a glass has a thick foamy head that remains there the entire time I drink it. Is this good or bad? The beer tastes great!

Comment: Sounds ideal.   Can you post a picture?

Comment: Yeah post a picture.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had this problem with multiple styles of beer when i didn't quite have a handle on carbonation (over carb)

something to think about!

Comment: How come this got down voted?

Answer (score 9):

Very hoppy beers often have increased foam and retention.  The polyphenols in the hops bind the proteins in the beer to create fantastic foam.  It's generally considered a very good thing.

Comment: It's not the polyphenols which promote foam formation/stability.  When polyphenols interact with barley hordeins (proline-rich proteins) they form trub in the kettle and chill-haze in the package.  When polyphenols interact with proline-rich proteins in the mouth, it creates astringency.  These are weak interactions, not "binding".    What promotes foam formation and stability is proteins (MW > 5000), gums like b-glucan and arabinoxylan, metal ions, and iso-alpha acids.    In this beer, it's likely due to more protein (high gravity) and more iso's (more hops).

Comment: BeerSensor, plus one for intense science.